# Find record through int found through varchar VS Find record through varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I knows, finding record through index(int) is faster than finding record through name(varchar).

## Case 1 : Find record through index(int) found through name(varchar)

- Database

  ```
  [names]
  idx(int) : index
  name(varchar) : name

  [records]
  idx(int) : record_idx
  name_idx(int) : name_index
  content(longtext) : content
  ```
- Processing

  **Case 1-1: Using Variable**

  ```
  results = SELECT `idx` FROM `names` WHERE `name` in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
  records = SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `name_idx` in (results);
  // results is just a variable in PHP
  // don't care of it
  ```

  **Case 1-2: Subquery**

  ```
  records = SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `name_idx` in
    (SELECT `idx` FROM `names` WHERE `name` in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3'));
  ```

  **Case 1-3: Join**

  ```
  records = SELECT `records`.* FROM `records`, `names`
     WHERE `names`.`name` in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
       AND `names`.`idx` = `records`.`name_idx`;
  ```

## Case 2 : Find record through name(varchar)

- Database

  ```
  [names]
  idx(int) : index
  name(varchar) : name

  [records]
  idx(int) : record_idx
  name_idx(int) : name_index
  name(varchar) : name
  content(longtext) : content
  ```
- Processing

  ```
  records = SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `name` in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
  ```

Which case is faster?

Comment: What about using `JOIN`?

Comment: @genespos I added a case 1-3.
And is it fastest in these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You can check your queries performance using Profiling. I have tested all of these queries. First one(case 1.1) is the worst one and between sub query & Join, Join is better option, Although both are almost same, but join is faster and cleaner one.

I am not clear about 2nd case. Because here you are not using two tables, when you will use only one table, it will perform better for small data & create problem for large data.